# vi commands to find specific letters

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I want ask about a commands on `vi`. start terminal and give this ->> `vi /etc/groups` and I want to find the entries corresponding to groups with names that end in `s` or `t` can someone help??

I already have tried the following commands

```
:/^t$ 
:/^s$
:wq
```

Comment: The `^` and `$` are *anchors* to tie the pattern to the beginning or end of the line, so your `^t$` matches a line containing only one `t`.

Comment: Since you're using Linux, I'd also advise using the `vigr` utility instead of editing `/etc/groups` directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/etc/group` file has three `:`-delimited fields, and the first one is the group name.

You want to find all groups whose names end with `s` or `t`:

```
/[st]:
```

This will find the next line in the buffer that contains an `s` or a `t` immediately followed by a `:`.

```
:g/[st]:
```

(short for `:global/[st]:/print`) to print them all.

Comment: more correctly for the first:  `/^[^:]*[st]:`  (to match only s or t endings in the FIRST field)

Comment: oh yes i understand!! Thank you for help! :)

Comment: @SakisDev Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).